# Function coloring in scratch buffer

Tags: font-lock, scratch-buffer

When I am typing in the scratch buffer, I type certain functions such as defun and while and they are recognized by the buffer and appear in purple. However, with other Lisp functions such as set or +, they do not appear in any color and I was wondering why that is.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defun` and `while` are macros, and are highlighted as such.

`set` and `+` are functions, and are not highlighted like macros.

Old versions of Emacs seem to have a list of specific macros to highlight, but more recent (possibly unreleased?) versions simply highlight all known macros.

Here are the docs on [functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Functions.html) and [macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Macros.html) so you can tell them apart. I admit, in Lisp the difference between calling a function and a macro is difficult to distinguish. This is both one of its great features, and great stumbling blocks.